# try/catch don't work with google script cell validation errors

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a setValue() operation in a script in a cell with validation and if I use a value not in the list it throws an error. That's fine.
But my problem is that when I put a try/catch to avoid the error it doesn't work and I keep receiving the same error

To reproduce the problem:
create new sheet and set validation in B2 list of values a,b,c, reject others

```
function test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  try { // don't work !!
    ss.getRange('B2').setValue('x'); // value not in validation list
  } catch(e) {Logger.log('error')}
}
```

Where is the problem???

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this:

```
function changevaluenotinlist() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange('J2').setValue(5);
}
```

In my sheet J2 is in a validated range using a list equal to 1,2,3 and no error is returned in the software.  So there should be no expectation to catch anything with a try/catch block.  The error is only shown in the spreadsheet user interface. I guess that's because this is meant to be a user interface method provide the user with acceptable responses and it simply provides them with a visible indication of an error.  I'd recommend that you get over it and move on.

Actually after selecting reject input I do get the error and your correct it does not get caught by a try catch block. Perhaps you should report it as an issue. Personally , I don't care.

Comment: I've tried again and if i use an integer value as 5 there is no error, but if I use a string value like 'x' it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) method after the set in order to get to the catch part.

```js
function test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  try { // don't work !!
    ss.getRange('B2').setValue('x'); // a text value not in validation list (with numeric values don´t fail)
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  } catch(e) {Logger.log('error')}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Flush fix the problem. It was yet answered in the issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/191817377